# SPOTIFY APP API: adding padding to playlist item .sp-item/changing ITEM_HEIGHT property in views.js

Tags: javascript, css, spotify

i'm trying to change the default look and feel for the spotify playlist generated with the list view.

padding is being applied correctly to .sp-item, but the height does not change (so it doesn't look padded). it seems as though the .sp-item height is set within spotify's own views.js with the variable ITEM_HEIGHT. this then dynamically positions the .sp-item elements according to height (and adds an inline style).

how do i alter this variable? i can't do it within view.js. is there another way to add padding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to answer my own question: the list view has an itemHeight property where you can specify the height. then just need to change the background height in the css and add the padding and it all works :)

Comment: Congrats on the fix!  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others may learn from your success.  Cheers~